# Looking for audio input/output management software

Tags: windows, audio

In a configuration with 3 output devices in Windows (8.1), I'd like to be able to link all 3 devices together so they play the same audio streams out each output simultaneously.

The stereo mix component that is hidden by default in the recording section accomplishes this for 1 additional output, but I think it also introduces a lag as it has to first listen and then play but I may be wrong there. Using my default speakers and a headset, I heard the speaker output before I heard the same sound on the headset.

Comment: Take a look at [virtual audio cable](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm) which may do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a really complicated problem.  Audio playback is driven by a hardware clock on each sound card.  Unless you have wired some coax to synchronize the clocks between each, they are going to run at different rates and will drift apart from each other over time.  Because of this, there really isn't software that can solve the issue.

[ASIO4ALL](http://www.asio4all.com/) attempts to do this by dropping buffers as necessary, but it isn't perfect and still has synchronization issues over time.  If your players support ASIO, this is the best place to start.